# Arquitetura para uma Aplicação JSF com APP Android

Tags: java, android, jsf

Estou na parte de planejamento de uma aplicação web que vou desenvolver para um Cliente. Serão CRUDs e alguns relatório, nada muito complicado.

No momento to bolando uma arquitetura para que essa aplicação consiga evoluir bem sem muito retrabalho.

Pretendo usar JSF, Hibernate e Bootstrap (por enquanto isso é o suficiente). Em um futuro não muito distante pode ser que o Cliente queira que eu desenvolva também uma APP Android para ser usada em conjunto com a aplicação web.

A dúvida vem agora. Qual a melhor forma de "organizar" o projeto para que se eu tiver que evoluir ele no futuro, seja fácil. Por exemplo, a aplicação web pode ter um cadastro de horas trabalhadas que podem ser cadastradas tanto na aplicação web como na APP Android.

Inicialmente pensei em trabalhar com "mini serviços", ou seja criar um serviço que será chamado em uma URl (/lancarHoras). Esse serviço espera um JSON com os dados do objeto que eu quero persistir, processa essas dados e responde para a "tela" com um OK ou ERRO. Dessa forma seria fácil evoluir no futuro, uma APP Android por exemplo só iria "consumir" esse serviço.

Vale a pena trabalhar desse jeito? Existe alguma outra forma melhor de se trabalhar nesse caso?

Comment: Thiago, bem-vindo. O pessoal está considerando que sua pergunta está procurando opiniões e votando para fechá-la. O StackOverflow é uma plataforma boa para perguntas e respostas objetivas mas não é adequado para pedir opiniões. Tem como você modificar a pergunta para garantir que sejam postadas respostas objetivas e não opiniões? O assunto é interessante, mas como a pergunta está escrita, está deixando abertura para cada um expressar sua opinião. Se souber inglês, veja como melhorar um a pergunta um pouco mais subjetiva: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: Não vejo como melhorar a pergunta para ela ficar mais objetica. Se for o caso e não estiver dentro das regras pode ser fechada ou até mesmo excluída.

Comment: Na verdade é para ficar mais objetiva. Eu vejo como, mas não gosto de mexer na intenção da perguntas de terceiros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usar Rest é a melhor solução. Um modelo de arquitetura que eu sei que funciona é:

Server(com regras de negócios) <------ VIEW

Note que não importa quem seja a VIEW, ela chamará o servidor e se comunicaria por JSON, por exemplo.

O problema começa com a seguinte pergunta: quem vai controlar a sessão? O usuário deverá estar logado para excluir um registro? O que acontecerá se alguém chamar esse método sem login?

Note que ao expor o servidor de negócios você terá sempre que blindar o acesso ao acesso de métodos privados.

---

#### Servidor de Negócios e um Servidor de Visualização

Ao usar JSF apenas você tem a vantagem de ter a seguinte arquitetura:

```
Server <----- View (JSF Mobile e Web)
```

Apenas seus managed beans serão chamados e com isso você não precisará expor seu servidor de negócios para o mundo, apenas para o servidor web.

---

#### Servidor de Negócios e duas Views Diferentes

O problema aparecerá quando você fizer a arquitetura abaixo:

```
View (App nativo) -----> Server <----- View (JSF Web)
```

Note que toda sua validação feita no JSF não será mais válida (validação de input, acesso a determinado método caso não tenha se logado, etc), pois você precisará ter uma validação dessas regras também no APP.

---

#### Soluções

Eu vejo algumas soluções para esse tipo de problema:

1. Você poderia ter todas as regras de negócio em um servidor e suas views serem inteiramente 'burras'. Fulano tentou acessar um método e não está logado, o server retornaria 401 e a view entenderia que um login seria necessário.
2. Ter um servidor no meio caminho (algo como um um controlador de sessão). Veja o exemplo abaixo:

   ```
   View (App nativo) -----> View Rules Server <----- View (JSF Mobile e Web)
                                   |-----> Server
   ```

   Esse View Rules Server receberia todas as chamadas HTTP e validaria se para determinada URL um login é necessário, se o cara está logado e se ele tem permissão para acessar esse recurso. 
   A vantagem dessa abordagem é que seu servidor de serviços preocuparia apenas com as regras de negócio em si e não com as questões de segurança.

---

#### Desacople seu serviço

Outro detalhe que você tem que sempre ter em mente é: não retorne seu objeto de negócio diretamente para a view.

Se você tiver a classe abaixo:

```java
@Entity
public Pessoa(){}
```

Evite retorná-la diretamente para a view. Qualquer alteração no negócio poderia significar em alteração na view. O ideal seria criar um VO para isso.

```java
public PessoaVO(){}
```

Esse cara seria o objeto retornando desacoplando assim sua camada de negócio da camada de visualização.

Comment: +1, exceto pelo último comentário. Na situação mencionada, imagino que uma alteração no código do servidor vai implicar em uma alteração na app e na webapp, ou seja, a mesma alteração seria feita três vezes. Ou quatro, se um VO estiver envolvido. Caso a API seja pública, então você tem razão, mas caso contrário, eu evitaria adicionar mais uma camada.

Comment: Nesse caso vou descordar. Existem diversos casos onde a regra do negócio pode variar sem variar a VIEW. Hoje eu trabalho em um server totalmente desacoplado da VIEW e em diversos casos eu não preciso realizar alterações em VIEW para implementar diversas ações. Nem toda alteração em servidor será  refletida na view.

Comment: De que forma se "blinda" os acessos aos métodos privados?

Comment: Oq seria blindar um método privado?

Answer (score 1):

Você está indo pelo o caminho certo.
Use [Rest](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)

Para consumir o Webservice usando Rest, use API [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), que é a implementação de referência do JavaEE.

E para pegar os Json e converter em objetos java, use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) do Google.

Comment: Só um adendo, para não ter problemas com a conversão do objeto ou lista para json, não faça mapeamentos bidirecionais.

Comment: @joelbarbosa, vou dar uma olhada nos links! Devo ir por esse caminho mesmo!

Comment: @user947, você diz A ter um objeto B entre seus atributos e B ter uma lista de A?

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa ao uso do Jersey é o Spring MVC que além de uma excelente implementação de recursos para API's Rest, possui diversos outros recursos para compor sua solução dentre eles pacotes para integração com redes sociais como facebook e twitter.

O processo de serializar e desserializar seus objetos é um ponto crítico para o desempenho do seu aplicativo/serviço (a depender do volume de dados de seus produtos). Quanto a esse aspecto é importante que você conheça o Jackson (rival do GSON).

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson